# How can I make a piano sound with function beep?

Tags: c

I need help, my code doesn't output the piano sound.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

//Dó: 261 Hz
//Ré: 293 Hz
//Mi: 329 Hz
//Fá: 349 Hz
//Sol: 392 Hz 
//Lá: 440 Hz
//Si: 493 Hz
//Dó(2): 522 Hz

int main(){
setlocale (LC_ALL,"Portuguese");
char nota = ' ';
int tempo = 150;
int som [8] = {261, 293, 329, 349, 392, 440,   493, 522}; 
puts("### PIANO VIRTUAL ###");
puts("\n m - Dó \n a - Ré \n r - Mi \n c - Fá \n    e - Sol \n l - Lá \n q - Si \n u - Dó*2");

nota = getchar();
switch (nota){
        case 'm': Beep(som[0]); tempo;
        case 'a': Beep(som[1]); tempo;
        case 'r': Beep(som[2]); tempo;
        case 'c': Beep(som[3]); tempo;  
        case 'e': Beep(som[4]); tempo;
        case 'l': Beep(som[5]); tempo;
        case 'q': Beep(som[6]); tempo;
    case 'u': Beep(som[7]); tempo;
    }       
}
```

I need that return a piano beep with the function "Beep"

I don't know what more to say so pls help me,

Comment: Where does `Beep` come from?

Comment: Can you please add the code where you defined ```Beep```?

Comment: @Todd how can I do it? Declare the function beep

Comment: When programming you can't just make stuff up and have the computer figure it out. You need to call existing functions or define them yourself and express *exactly* what the computer is supposed to do.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `tempo;` by itself does absolutely nothing in C code.

Comment: On top of that you need to learn how `switch` works and in particular the *fall-through* behaviour. If you don't `break` it will just trickle through to the next condition. There's absolutely nothing wrong with learning, but these problems indicate you don't have a good reference to work from. Consider getting a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

### Standard C has *no* function for sounds.

Check by reading [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (the C11 standard) or [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) reference. There is no `Beep` there. Read also the [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) book.

Some [operating systems](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) provide [API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface)s and [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_(computing)) to make sounds. But **some computers** (e.g. the web server providing you this content) **don't even have any loudspeakers or devices capable of producing a nice sound** (apart their fans). **Any sound-related function is either operating system or computer specific.** On an [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/), [your C code](https://www.instructables.com/id/Arduino-Basics-Making-Sound/) producing a sound would be very different than one for my Linux desktop.

On Linux, read about [ALSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Linux_Sound_Architecture) and consider using [libsdl](https://www.libsdl.org/) (which is an abstraction layer working on several OSes). On Windows, study the [WinAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API).

You could code something interacting with your web browser and have your web browser produce a sound (if your computer can do that). Then learn [more](https://www.w3schools.com/) about the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol and [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5) and [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/).

You could find several libraries (for Linux at least) providing an API for HTTP services. For example [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion).

Read of course [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

If you compile your  C code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/), be sure to enable all warnings and debug info, so compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`. Learn also to use some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), etc....